# Redux state showing previous or default value while submitting function called

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux, redux-thunk

Async await is not functioning properly on my React project. It is not awaiting a response. Redux state displaying the previous or default value while calling the function but outside the function, it's working fine. As you can see, I print the employee from the selector in the handleSubmit function, however this prints the prior or default state, and I need the updated value to proceed. Data is not being awaited.

```js
// handle submit function 

const handleSubmit = async(values) => {
  const personalData = new FormData();
  Object.keys(personalValue).forEach((key) => personalData.append(key, personalValue[key]));


  await dispatch(addEmployeePersonal(personalData));
  console.log(employee) // Inside the function Employee prints default or previous state value

};

console.log(employee) // Here it's working fine, Outside the function employee prints updated value


// Selector
const {
  employee,
  employeeLoading,
  employeeError
} = useSelector((state) => state.employee);

// Redux Reducer
export const employeeReducer = (state = {
  employee: 0
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_REQUEST:
    case EMPLOYEE_ID_REQUEST:
    case NEW_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_REQUEST:
    case NEW_EMPLOYEE_OFFICIAL_REQUEST:
    case DELETE_EMPLOYEE_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        employeeLoading: true,
        employee: 0,
      };
    case UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_SUCCESS:
    case UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_OFFICIAL_SUCCESS:
    case EMPLOYEE_ID_SUCCESS:
    case NEW_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_SUCCESS:
    case NEW_EMPLOYEE_OFFICIAL_SUCCESS:
    case DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        employeeLoading: false,
        employee: action.payload,
      };
    case UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_FAILED:
    case UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_OFFICIAL_FAILED:
    case EMPLOYEE_ID_FAILED:
    case NEW_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_FAILED:
    case NEW_EMPLOYEE_OFFICIAL_FAILED:
    case DELETE_EMPLOYEE_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        employeeLoading: false,
        employeeError: action.payload,
      };
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        employeeError: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// Redux Action
export const addEmployeePersonal = (info) => async(dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: NEW_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_REQUEST
    });

    const {
      data
    } = await coreAxios.post("/api/Employee/PersonalInfo", info);
    dispatch({
      type: NEW_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: NEW_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_FAILED,
      payload: error.response,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason: At the first render of the component, the value `employee` is `0`. You trigger the form submit handler, it uses the `employee`, which value is `0`. Even though you dispatch an action and try to change it, **the `handleSubmit` still uses the `employee` evaluated in the first render(execution of function component) of the component before finishing executing**. `await dispatch(thunk())` will NOT wait for next render of the component. That's why you get the previous value of `employee`.

After `handleSubmit` finishes its execution, the state in the redux store has been changed, the redux store context provider will subscribe to that change and rerender the children. Your component will re-render(the second execution of the function component), `useSelector` will execute again and return the new `employee`. A new `handleSubmit` function will be declared and it reference the new `employee` defined in the function component scope.

There are two solutions:

**Option 1: `useEffect`**

```
useEffect(() => {
  // get the latest employee to do something.
}, [employee])
```

**Option 2: return action payload in thunk so that you can get it after dispatching action**

```
export const addEmployeePersonal = (info) => async(dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: NEW_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_REQUEST
    });

    const {
      data
    } = await coreAxios.post("/api/Employee/PersonalInfo", info);
    dispatch({
      type: NEW_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
    return data;  // here
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: NEW_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_FAILED,
      payload: error.response,
    });
  }
};
```

```
const handleSubmit = async(values) => {
  const personalData = new FormData();
  Object.keys(personalValue).forEach((key) => personalData.append(key, personalValue[key]));

  const newEmployee = await dispatch(addEmployeePersonal(personalData));
  // Do something with newEmployee.
};
```